# Need help for checking if user is online

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL so I kinda need some help.

```
                        <?php
                        function Agotime($date)
                        {
                            if(empty($date)) {
                                return "No date provided";
                            }

                            $periods         = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
                            $lengths         = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

                            $now             = time();
                            $unix_date         = strtotime($date);

                               // check validity of date
                            if(empty($unix_date)) {    
                                return "Unknown";
                            }

                            // is it future date or past date
                            if($now > $unix_date) {    
                                $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
                                $tense         = "ago";

                            } else {
                                $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
                                $tense         = "from now";
                            }

                            for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
                                $difference /= $lengths[$j];
                            }

                            $difference = round($difference);

                            if($difference != 1) {
                                $periods[$j].= "s";
                            }

                            return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
                        }

                        $date = $run_user['lastloggedin'];
                        $result = Agotime($date); // 2 days ago
                        $serverjoins = $run_user['server_joins'];
                        ?>
```

I have that code, and it's working as it should be, but there is one problem, I have another row in my database called online, and if this is set to true, I want it to display Online instead of for example Last Seen: 1 Hour ago
Can anyone tell me where to put what?

Comment: It's not clear. Where database result? How do you combine it with this function?

Comment: @Javad I don't understand your reply, could you be a bit clearer?

Comment: I mean is `$date` coming from Database? This function you provide is just for comparing dates and times

Comment: You should create a table that holds temporary session data and query that to check if somebody is online, deleting the row when the session data is deleted

Comment: How do you define "online"?

Comment: @Javad Yes, it's from the database, it's a `TIMEDATE` so I am trying to fetch if the user is online, so everytime someone logs on the server, the value in the database changes to true, so the row online would be equals to true, so what I'm trying to get in the code is that if the row online is true, then print Online, else it will show `$result`, which shows last time seen online..

Comment: That makes sense. You can do this before calling this function. I mean wherever you call this function first check if the user is Online then return 'Online' otherwise call this function and return the value of this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $run_user contains the result from your database, and in addition to the lastloggedin field there is an online field:

```
if ('true' == $run_user['online'] {
  $result = 'Online now!';
} else {
  $date = $run_user['lastloggedin'];
  $result = Agotime($date);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I don't know why, but when I change the value from true to false in the database, it doesn't change the result, it just keeps saying Online Now!

Comment: Sorry, should have been 'true' not true. See if that fixes it.